# Is there any way or formula to calculate Number of Columns generated from LEFT, RIGHT, INNER , OUTER,CROSS

Tags: sql

I attended few interviews, and this question was common, Given Two Table- A & B
Primary & Foreign Key- A_ID B_ID

```
A_ID
1
2
2
3
5
4
3
5

B_ID 2 1 1 3 3 3 4 5
```

Questions are asked like- How many Columns will be generated after Applying the following set of joins-
LEFT, RIGHT, OUTER, INNER, CROSS

It's evident that we can calculate the no. of columns generated through visual calculations, but is there any formula for answering faster??

Comment: `JOIN`s do not generate columns, they generate rows.  The number of columns is whatever is selected.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty simple. Unless you define a projection that states otherwise (i.e. use `SELECT *`) the number of columns of the result is the number of columns from one plus the number of columns from the other table, for all joins.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Ooops... Yeah, I meant that. Bad mistake... Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

`JOIN`s of any sort do not generate columns.  They generate rows.

The number of columns is whatever is selected.

Either you have misinterpreted the question or it is a trick question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've misremembered your interview - the number of columns arising from the joins shown is "two" in all cases (you've shown one column from two tables, joining will generate a result set in which there are two columns available to select. The number of columns produced by the query depends on which of these are selected and how many times. The same column can be selected multiple times. Other columns that are not part of the resultset from the join can be added too

I think your question was intended to assess your understanding of JOINs as a process and I think they wanted to know the number of ROWS produced by joining those result sets

### INNER JOIN

Sum up the results of multiplying the number of appearances of a value on one side, by the number of appearances of a value on the other side

```
1: once on the left, twice on the right: 1x2=2
2: 2x1=2
3: 2x3=6
4: 1x1=1
5: 2x1=2

2+2+6+1+2 = 13
```

### OUTER JOIN

As per inner join but any values that appear 0 times on the opposite side shall be considered as appearing 1 time on that opposite side.

Whether it is declared as LEFT or RIGHT join, and which way round the tables are written, determines which is the "opposite" side of the join

```
A LEFT JOIN B - A is on the left, it is a left join, A is the current side, B is the opposite side
A RIGHT JOIN B - A is on the left, it is a right join, B is the current side, A is the opposite side
B LEFT JOIN A - B is on the left, it is a left join, B is the current side, A is the opposite side
B RIGHT JOIN A - B is on the left, it is a right join, A is the current side, B is the opposite side
```

For example if A_ID had 6, 6, 6, 6 and B_ID never had any 6, and it was A LEFT JOIN B meaning that A is the current side and there are no 6 on the opposite, they shall be considered as appearing 1 time on the opposite.

Thus the formula uses 4x1 instead of 4x0 because there are four occurrences of 6 on the current and 0-but-consider-as-1 on the opposite

If it was A RIGHT JOIN B then B is the "current" side, A is the "opposite" side, the value 6 appears 0 times on the current side so the formula uses 0x4. We only ever up from 0 to 1 for the *opposite* side, bit the "current" side. If there are 0 occurrences on the current side we keep 0x4 and the rows disappear from the output

You don't have any rows that meet this criteria (some on one side but not the other), so the left and right joins are the same as an inner here

Avoid using RIGHT JOIN - rewrite them (and turn the tables round) so they become LEFT joins. It makes it a lot easier to reason about what rows are output because SQL processes things in a FROM clause in left to right order. Try to do all your inner joins first, then all your left joins. Any table that links to a left joined table also needs to be left joined if you don't want to lose rows

### CROSS

The number of rows on the left multiplied by the number of rows on the right

Answer (score 0):

I think they've asked you about the no of records affected or displayed for using each of operations.If not, numbers of columns i.e. (A_ID,B_ID) can be chosen depending on your interviewer wish to display